# Add Post As a menu Item

Tags: posts

When I write a post, I want
to put it under one of the menu categories so it shows up. How can I do
that?

Please Help

Comment: Please search our site. We have some solutions for that.

Comment: can you specifically say which solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the admin end and to the Appearence->Menus and then add the post under the category menu. If you dont see the posts be3ing displayed on the left side of the page, click on screen options on top and then select posts and the list of posts will be displayed inb the page in the left bottom corner. Then you can select the post and add it.

Comment: how do you add a page, if that page isn't available to be added in the "edit menu" option?